How to fix this Vercel Error - Content Security Policy?
I deployed my backend on vercel. but when I opened the link, it is showing this error. I have no idea where to fix it as I am a beginner. Can someone help me with this?
Vercel error
I've already deployed the front end on Vercel and I connected it with the backend running locally, it was working perfectly. then I deployed the backend on Vercel, it is showing the above error.

Something in your setup has introduced what seems to be a default and very strict Content Security Policy. This could be Vercel, but it could also be set by web servers, proxies and others. You will need to figure out who is setting "Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'". You'll most likely see it in a response header, but it could also be in a meta tag. Then you'll need to adjust the policy to allow what you need or remove it.

Thank you for your advice!
I deployed it on render, and it deployed successfully. I browsed for solutions on the internet, and I saw a discussion on github where people had similar issues deploying there nextjs project, and it seems to be working; however, when I tried to implement it for my react app, it did not work and showed the same error.
